# Update conflicts with the Address module

Tags: 8, commerce

I am trying to update Drupal 8.4 with the *Drupal Commerce* module version 2, but the *Address* module and Drupal conflict with each other.

I have tried using addressing ^1.0 but that is no help I think the dependencies have changed in Drupal Commerce and there is no new supporting documentation.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>    Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for drupal/commerce ^2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce[2.0.0].
> - drupal/commerce 2.0.0 requires drupal/entity ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/entity[1.x-dev, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-alpha4, 1.0.0-alpha3, 1.0.0-alpha2, 1.0.0-alpha1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Problem 2
>
> - drupal/address 1.0.0 requires commerceguys/addressing ~1.0 -> satisfiable by commerceguys/addressing[1.x-dev, v1.0.0-beta1, v1.0.0-beta2, v1.0.0-beta3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> - drupal/address 1.1.0 requires commerceguys/addressing ~1.0 -> satisfiable by commerceguys/addressing[1.x-dev, v1.0.0-beta1, v1.0.0-beta2, v1.0.0-beta3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> - drupal/address 1.2.0 requires commerceguys/addressing ~1.0 -> satisfiable by commerceguys/addressing[1.x-dev, v1.0.0-beta1, v1.0.0-beta2, v1.0.0-beta3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> - Installation request for drupal/address  ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/address[1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.0].

Comment: If drush is in your composer file, try requiring drush 9 instead of drush 8.

Comment: You don't need to provide all the dependencies of commerce, that's the big advantage of it. Just specificy the things you actually need explicitly (e.g. just commerce) and then let composer figure out the rest.

Comment: I updated to drush 9 this gives the frustrating problem of not being able to drush dl modules anymore. In any respect, it does not help and gives the same issue.  I use update using composer update --with-dependencies but its the same problem. Its annoying as I spend half Drupal development these days fighting composer.